# How to create a POI database for OsmAnd?

Tags: maps, offline-map, osmand

[OsmAnd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand) is a map/navigation app.

On top of the map, I would like to display "Points of Interest" (POI), for instance my city's best restaurants.

I already have a CSV file containing for each POI: name, latitude, longitude.

How to make OsmAnd use this data?

The wiki page [How To Use Your Own POI Database](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToUseYourOwnPOIDatabase) suggests it is possible but does not give any specific instructions.

By reading [this unanswered question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43344/restore-osmand-poi-list), I get a feeling that somehow converting my CSV to ODB might be part of the solution.

I would like the database to be easily downloadable/usable by anyone.

*For the curious: Actually, my long-term goal is to create a database of all POIs in the [Wikivoyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/) travel guide (maybe split by country if too big).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but worth trying: I did the same with *Locus Maps*. I created a KML, which imported fine, and could be used as layer there (*Locus* even supports KMZ containing images and more, so you could use that for a "self-made travel guide").

The article [Using KML Files](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/CreatingKMLFile) on the same site suggests at least the KML part should work with *OsmAnd* as well, so I considered placing this as answer (instead of making it a comment). This article even explicitly mentions POIs – which probably is the reason your linked article contained that few details:

> You may use any format containing your POIs, if you are able to convert it to osm format.

and

> All points inside the kml file are converted into osm points, assigning them some properties like tourism category and museum type.

Note the categories mentioned here match those on your linked article.

Comment: Thanks! I have copied the `.osm` file on that page, converted it to `.odb` using OsmAndMapCreator, pushed the resulting `.odb` to `/sdcard/osmand`, but OsmAnd does not show any POI...

Comment: I'm not used to OsmAnd – but could it be you have to "activate" the "additional layer" somewhere in the app? Imagine your card full of `.odb` files with overlapping info, I would hope there's a way to select which ones to use ;)

Comment: I have found how to use it :-) http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55656/how-to-import-a-odb-poi-file-in-osmand

Comment: So the only thing left was to either wait or reboot the device? In that case, I'd report that as bug to the dev, honestly. Doesn't sound normal to me. But glad you managed – and thanks for linking to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this:

- Transform the data from [.CSV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-CSV/) to [.OSM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-OSM/)
- Download and run OsmAndMapCreator
- In OsmAndMapCreator, let only "Build POI index" checked, then click File > Build .obf from osm file...
- Select the .osm file
- Distribute the resulting [.OBF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-OBF/) file. Users can easily [use it with OsmAnd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55656/how-to-import-a-obf-poi-file-in-osmand).