# How to import a .obf POI file in OsmAnd

Tags: maps, offline-map, osmand

I created this `Data.osm` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version='0.5' generator='GPSBabel-1.4.0'>
  <node id='-1' visible='true' lat='41.890121' lon='12.492265'>
    <tag k='name' v='place01'/>
    <tag k='note' v='place01'/>
    <tag k='tourism' v='museum'/>
  </node>
</osm>
```

Then I converted it to `Data.obf` using OsmAndMapCreator.

How to have OsmAnd show this POI on the maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Open OBF file using filesystem browser**

Use a tool for navigating your phone's filesystem. Navigate to the file you wish to import and choose to open the file with OsmAnd.

On Android there are several tools for navigating to the file, one example is Total Commander.

**Obsolete method, pre 2022**

The solution below does not work on recent versions (since some time in 2022) but is still here for completeness. It is what was originally suggested in this answer.

1. Copy the `.obf` file to your OsmAnd folder, for instance `/sdcard/osmand`.
2. In OsmAnd, enable the "POI > Any" layer.
3. Sometimes it does not work immediately, in such case restart your phone (there might be faster methods but at least restarting works)